# how to force google chrome/firefox to use Internet explorer web browser control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have developed a web page which is very much compatible with IE8.

Now the problem is that alignment of certain elements like span, radio button etc appear to be different in google chrome and firefox!!

Is there  any way with which I can force the Firefox and chrome to parse and render the webpage exactly like IE8?? 
I tried adding meta tags

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=8">
```

I also tried

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
```

But that doesnt seem to work.

I tried using [IE_Tab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IE_Tab) which made the content in chrome exactly look like how it looks in IE. But its not possible to make all users install this, so is there a way in which i can direct browsers to use the IE Webbrowser control by any means ?! 
Is there any scripts/code snippet which will instruct/redirect the browser to do this??

Comment: IE_Tab does not make chrome look like IE, it makes chrome **use** IE. That is, it just wraps IE in a chrome tab. This won't work for mac, linux, or other operating system and is not supported by chrome, its's just a hacky add-on.

Comment: @Justin808 Ya it will work only for windows!! 
Is it possible to do the same using any script?? i mean is it possible to make chrome show content like html using any tag script or any way?

Comment: As a web developer myself you wanting to go down this route make me die a little inside.  No there is no way to script it. There is nothing you can do other than to check that your user is using IE8 and if not redirect to a page saying that to use your site they must 1) be on windows 2) downgrade to IE8.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making the page look correct in browsers that follow web standards first (Firefox, Chrome). Then fix up for IE later. There is no way to do what you're suggesting. Those meta tags are for making later versions of IE behave like earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks 
But since all windows user will have IE by default we thought making it IE8 compatible will be good. Btw the IE-Tab addon (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en) made the web page look just the same as in IE so i just thought it can be achieved via some kinda scripting

Answer (score 0):

Coding for IE8 first is going to cause you many headaches, even later version of IE will have issues. You are *much* better off coding for Chrome or Firefox first as they are *much* more standards compliant, and then make tweeks so IE8 looks OK.

If you insist on coding for IE first, code to IE10 first as its more **standards compliant** than IE8. If you insist on IE8 first, then every other browser will just look bad :)